# How to render a View to the right of parent node in ARCore sceneform

Tags: android, arcore, sceneform

Using ViewRenderable I am rendering layout file. I gave fixed width and height for the layout file

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="500dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">
// Add design
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Now I am building layout as ViewRenderable

```
 // Build a renderable from a 2D View.
        CompletableFuture<ViewRenderable> meterOne =
                ViewRenderable.builder().setView(this, R.layout.meter).build();

     CompletableFuture.allOf(circle,
                meterOne, meterTwo)
                .handle(
                        (notUsed, throwable) -> {
                            // When you build a Renderable, Sceneform loads its resources in the background while
                            // returning a CompletableFuture. Call handle(), thenAccept(), or check isDone()
                            // before calling get().

                            if (throwable != null) {
                                DemoUtils.displayError(this, "Unable to load renderable", throwable);
                                return null;
                            }

                            try {
 Meters.add(meterOne.get());
 } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException ex) {
                                DemoUtils.displayError(this, "Unable to load renderable", ex);
                            }
```

After that I need to render this `ViewRenderable` Object into the node

```
        Node sunVisual = new Node();
        sunVisual.setParent(sun);
        sunVisual.setRenderable(Meters.get(0)); // View
        sunVisual.setLocalScale(new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f));
```

Now I need to add another node to the right of sunVisual node

```
            Node node = new Node();
            node.setParent(sunVisual );
            node.setRenderable(Meters.get(1));
            node.setLocalPosition(new Vector3(2.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
```

This code works well on google pixel 2 devices but I am getting small space in nokia x6 device

**Google pixel 2 screenshot**[image: Google pixel 2 image]

**Nokia x6 screenshot**[image: Nokia x6 screenshot]

How to get the rendered view width and height in meter?

How to set local position to the right of parent node based on the parent node rendered view size

Help me to fix this issue thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found solution to fix the above mentioned issue that I faced.

```
    Node node = new Node();
    node.setParent(parent);
    Renderable renderable = Meters.get(i);
    renderable.setShadowReceiver(false);
    renderable.setShadowCaster(false);
 ((ViewRenderable) renderable).setSizer(new FixedWidthViewSizer(2));
    node.setRenderable(renderable);
    node.setLocalPosition(new Vector3(2.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
```

We can use setSizer to set width and height for `ViewRendarable`

```
 ((ViewRenderable) renderable).setSizer(new FixedWidthViewSizer(2));
```